# Parallel GET requests for different domains with threading module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, python-multithreading

I expect to have maybe something like 100k URLs from different domains. I wrote this code which has a list of URLs in `all_urls` and forms `N` threads to run in one batch. Currently I'm using `threading` module to make these requests in parallel.

```
import requests
import os
import threading
import time

all_urls = [] # a list of URLs to request, can have up to 100k

global success, fail
success = 0
fail = 0

def func(url_to_request):
    global success, fail
    try:
        r = requests.get(url_to_request, timeout=5)
        c = r.content
        success = success +1
    except:
        fail = fail +1
    return

batch_count = 1
N = 200 # number of threads
all_threads_urls = []
time_start = time.time()

for item in all_urls:
    all_threads_urls.append(item)
    if all_urls.index(item) == len(all_urls)-1 or len(all_threads_urls) == N:
        # call it
        all_threads = []
        for link in all_threads_urls:
            current_thread = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(link,))
            all_threads.append(current_thread)
            current_thread.start()

        for thr in all_threads:
            thr.join()

        all_threads_urls = [] # for the next batch
        time_end = time.time()

        print "Request number", all_urls.index(item)+1, "Good:", success, "Bad:", fail, "Duration:", round(time_end - time_start,2 ), "seconds."
        time_start = time_end
```

Results for this are a bit weird, it seems that the script starts very fast but then slows down a lot (see image). Printed durations are for each batch. 
[image]

Can someone explain what is the bottleneck here? Is there maybe a better module for this or there is no way around this?

Comment: I don't know what's causing the slowdown, perhaps it has to do with what URLs are in the list (some website are faster than others and the content on each can vary a great deal). Regardless, you need to use `Lock`s to prevent concurrent access to any `global` variables.

Comment: BTW, Python guru Raymond Hettinger gave a very interesting [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zinZmE3Ogk&feature=youtu.be) on concurrency, and one of the examples he uses is very similar to what your code does.

Comment: I restarted my PC and ran again, results were much more even, took like 17 seconds for each batch. I noticed that it goes faster if I interrupt execution and rerun for those that it already requested before. I'll have to gather these 100k URLs and just see how it goes I guess.

Comment: Regarding global variables, here it's just for counting purposes. Usually the function would take URL and a unique save path for each request where it would save contents.